# How to merge 2 xpath in one

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**Html**

```
<li class="wdappchrome-ai" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResult" tabindex="-2" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3">
<span data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultFullText">
    <span style="font-weight:500">
        <span data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken" style="font-weight:400">mike</span>
        <span data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken" style="font-weight:400">diana</span>
    </span>
</span>
</li>
```

I am getting user full name divided into `spans` so I want to build xpath which returns me combine text of both/multiple span from single `list`.

For now I am using 2 or more xpath based on name of user divided into span.

I use : `//li[.//span[text()='mike']]`  `//li[.//span[text()='diana']]`

Then I do `gettext()` for above both xpath and merge using java grammatically. So I am looking for solution which give me full text of all `span` within particular `li` tag from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath to match element by one of the spans:

```
//li[.//span='diana' or .//span='mike']
```

or by both spans:

```
//li[.//span='diana' and .//span='mike']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the full text of all span within particular li tag in a single line you can use the following code block :

```
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> firstName_lastname = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='wdappchrome-ai']//span[@data-automation-id='searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken']"));
for (WebElement fN_lN:firstName_lastname)
    nameList.add(fN_lN.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
System.out.println(nameList);
```

Comment: Is there any chance to achieve it using only xpath as I have heard that list webelement is slower than xpath if we have large data and then select. Also in my case class names are changing frequently :(

Comment: Well, `findElement` will always return a single `WebElement`. But as you need to deal with 2 different `WebElements` the solution will be based on either multiple `xpath`s (your original way) or you have to use `findElements`. Now, I can provide you a `css` on demand but that necessarily won't guarantee a faster search either. As I can see the `class names` involved is not dynamic as such. Incase of dynamic `class names` we can easily adapt making out `xpath`/`css` dynamic.